# How to extract the names of all bookmarks in a Word Xml Document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, ms-word

I have a word Document in Xml format with multiple entries like so :

```
    <aml:annotation aml:id="0" w:type="Word.Bookmark.Start" w:name="CustomerName"/>
```

I want to retrieve a collection of these but cannot see how to get past

```
    foreach (XElement ann in doc.Root.Descendants(aml + "annotation"))
```

In other words I can get all annotations, but cannot see how to filter to just retrieve bookmarks.  The namespaces `aml` and `w` are declared like this

```
    XNamespace w = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
    XNamespace aml = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core";
```

Could someone give me a push ?

---

I resolved the issue as follows

```
        XNamespace w = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w"); 
        XNamespace aml = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("aml");

        foreach (string bookm in doc.Descendants(aml + "annotation")
                                    .Where(e => e.Attributes(w + "type")
                                    .Any(a => a.Value == "Word.Bookmark.Start"))
                                    .Select(b => b.Attribute(w + "name").Value))
        {
             ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var names = from a in doc.Root.Descendants(aml + "annotation"))
            where (string)a.Attribute(w + "type") == "Word.Bookmark.Start"
            select (string)a.Attribute(w + "name");
```

Lambda syntax:

```
doc.Root.Descendants(aml + "annotation")
        .Where(a => (string)a.Attribute(w + "type") == "Word.Bookmark.Start")
        .Select(a => (string)a.Attribute(w + "name"))
```

Comment: You are right that what I want is a collection of names, but my difficulty is getting only "Word.Bookmark.Start" elements.  There are other annotations which do not qualify.

Comment: @HughJones just add filter. Updated my answer

Comment: Both of those techniques return an empty list.  If I take out the `where` clause they both return a list of 50 nulls.  This is essentially where I had got up to with my own attempts.  My problem is, I think, That I don't know how to handle a namespace embedded in an attribute e.g. `w:type="Word.Bookmark.Start"`

Comment: Apologies - I made a mistake with my original namespace declarations which may explain why your suggestion didn't work for me.  In any case , reading the namespaces from the file itself is more reliable, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not for XML but maybe helps you.

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BookmarkStart> BookMarks = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<BookmarkStart>();
foreach (BookmarkStart current in BookMarks)
{
    //Do some...
}
```